# What does using `__get__` on a function do?

Tags: python

for the function,

```
def add(a, b):
  return a + b
```

when I do,

```
add.__get__(object(), object)
```

```
<bound method add of <object object at 0x7f3c7af42b90>>
```

```
add.__get__(list(), list)
```

```
<bound method add of []>
```

```
add.__get__(bool(), bool)
```

```
<bound method add of False>
```

what is happening here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660871/python-get-method

Answer (score 3):

Functions are *descriptors* and use the descriptor protocol to bind the instance the method is called on to the first argument. This is how "self works". So, if you look at the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) it gives you an example of how it would be implemented in Python:

```
class Function:
    ...

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return MethodType(self, obj)
```

So, here are examples of calling the returned callable with different types of objects:

```
>>> def frobnicate(first):
...     return first.foo + 1
...
>>> class Foo:
...     foo = 42
...
>>> class Bar:
...     foo = "bar"
...
>>> class Baz:
...     bar = 42
...
>>> frobnicate.__get__(Foo())()
43
>>> frobnicate.__get__(Bar())()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in frobnicate
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>>> frobnicate.__get__(Baz())()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in frobnicate
AttributeError: 'Baz' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

And of course, putting the function in some class namespace makes it act like any other method automatically:

```
>>> Foo.frobnicate = frobnicate
>>> Foo().frobnicate()
43
```

Note, you can mentally think of `MethodType` as just something like:

```
def bind_first(func, obj):
    def bound(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return bound
```

Although, if you check the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), it shows a closer implementation (in Python, instead of C):

Methods can be created manually with types.MethodType which is roughly equivalent to:

```
class MethodType:
    "Emulate PyMethod_Type in Objects/classobject.c"

    def __init__(self, func, obj):
        self.__func__ = func
        self.__self__ = obj

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = self.__func__
        obj = self.__self__
        return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

Which is basically doing the same thing as the `bind_first` function I gave as an example... (although, again, it's using a class and it also creates the `__func__` and `__self__` arguments that bound-methods have).

Comment: what is ‘MethodType’?

Comment: It's just `types.MethodType`, but you could *also* just implement that by hand, it's in the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)

Comment: @apostofes edited to add it explicitly to the answer

Answer (score 0):

it appears that,

```
def f():
  pass
```

when I do,

```
hasattr(f, '__get__')
```

then, it returns `True`

when I do,

```
class A:
  pass
```

```
a = A()
```

```
f.__get__(a, A) # I think the second argument is optional here
# so, even, f.__get__(a) would give same result
```

it returns,

```
<bound method f of <__main__.A object at 0x7f9c7568dd10>>
```

which means that our function is similar to something like this,

```
class B:
  def func_(self):
    pass
```

```
b = B()
```

```
b.func_
```

```
<bound method B.func_ of <__main__.B object at 0x7f9c7563cc50>>
```

and then when I call the function on top,

```
f.__get__(a)()
```

then, it gives an error,

```
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

which means, that I am passing the instance here,
similar to `func_`, where,
the first argument `self` refers to the instance of the class `B`.

so, the function we have on top, becomes a bound method, and if I change it to,

```
def f(self):
  print(self)
```

and then run,

```
f.__get__(a)()
```

it gives me,

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7f9c7568dd10>
```

one more thing to notice here is that we could bind our function to a class also, which would make it a class method,

```
f.__get__(A)
```

```
<bound method func of <class '__main__.A'>>
```

where,

```
f.__get__(A)()
```

gives,

```
<class '__main__.A'>
```

which is similar to,

```
class C:
  @classmethod
  def x(cls):
    print(cls)
```

```
C.x
```

```
<bound method C.x of <class '__main__.C'>>
```

or we could keep our function as a static method, without binding it to an instance or a class.

```
f.__get__(1)
```

```
<bound method func of 1>
```

where,

```
f.__get__(1)()
```

gives,

```
1
```

here, `f` would be a function with the first argument equal to `1`.